# Is there a source control friendly workflow for FireStore Emulator initial data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

FireStore local emulator is great and help building apps much faster and easier.
I saw there is an `--import` and `--export-on-exit` which can specify directories from/to which data will be imported and exported.

That is very useful but the files created are binary and will not play nice with source control.

Is there a workflow which allows to use JSON file format to import and export the initial data?

Comment: The Firebase Emulators is still in Beta. Currently, JSON file format has not been supported. But you can explain this feature request of Firebase Emulators at [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Comment: Thank you @ShawnDiWu - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/165648142